# Convert String (timestamp) to integer

Tags: java, string, integer

I have to convert a String "1392298553937999872" into an int. The string is a timestamp. Normally this should be possible to convert it into a int by using:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(1392298553937999872);
```

But I receive the following exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "1392298553937999872"

If I use double it works, but the number is wrong. So how can I convert a timestamp into an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number is greater than the max value of `Integer` use `Long`

```
Long l = new Long("1392298553937999872");
```

Answer (score 4):

convert the string to long.

```
String a="1392298553937999872";
long b= Long.parseLong(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The number you're trying to convert exceeds the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` value. You'd better use `BigInteger`.

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("1392298553937999872");
```

Comment: Why use `BigDecimal` for an integer? Either `Long` or `BigInteger` would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

The value you're trying to convert is greater than the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2,147,483,647), you should use one of the alternative types [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html), [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
Long bigValue = Long.parseLong("1392298553937999872");
// ...
Long bigValue = new Long("1392298553937999872");
// ..
Long bigValue = Long.valueOf("1392298553937999872");
// ...
BigInteger bigValue = new BigInteger("1392298553937999872");
```

If adding an additional library and the values might vary, you can also use apache commons' NumberUtils. The method [NumberUtils.createNumber(String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#createNumber%28java.lang.String%29) will adapt based on the provided input:

```
Number bigValue = NumberUtils.createNumber(inputString);
```